# Can we deploy Two stand alone projects On Production Level and connect it together

Tags: python, node.js, reactjs, django

My Social Media Team want to use NodeJs(for backend) and ReactJs(for frontend). and my other team want to use Django(for backend) and ReactJs(Frontend). My Question is Can We connect these two Program together on the production level and make it a single project at time of deployment?

Comment: In which manner do they need to be connected? You can have the front end (react) communicate with 2 separate backends, if that is what you need.

Comment: you can use nxinx with proxy reverse to direct each application to a port. and the front end as well

Answer (score 0):

You can develop a backend project in one languague/framework and another with a different languague/framework and send request from your ReactJs frontend to them without any problem, but they are still two different projects and they're going to need to be deployed independently. They will have different configuration properties and dependencies. Also you can allow them to communicate with each other if you need to, through HTTP requests or event messages.

There's a backend architecture for something similar called **microservices**, where an application can be divided into multiple small, loosely coupled, independently deployabled applications. There's a lot of documentation about it, maybe is something you can work with your two teams. [here](https://microservices.io/) you can find information about microservices.